# Using the std::ofstream only works once?

Tags: c++, std

so I'm having trouble with this function I created in c++, it seems whenever I am calling logger function, it will only write once to the file I writing to. A second calling to the function will have no effect on it what so ever. I would like to confirm if this is the correct implementation of std::ofstream. So in main, when I call the instance of communicator::logger like the following:

main.cpp

```
communicator.logger("test1"); //A file called myLog.txt, inside has "test1" with a new line
communicator.logger("test2"); //This one won't show up.
```

communicator.cpp

```
void Communicator::logger(char *logData)
{
  //Get the current time
  time_t     now = time(0);
  struct tm  tstruct;
  char       buf[80];
  tstruct = *localtime(&now);
  strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);

  //Get absolute path of the appdata/local directory
  char* path = getenv("LOCALAPPDATA");
  strcat(path, "\\myApp\\myLog.txt");
  std::cout << path;    
  std::ofstream log(path, std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);
  log << buf << " " << logData << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you try it without std::ios_base::out

Comment: You never allocate memory to store the full path, so you have undefined behavoir. Avoid using c-style strings when you can, so in this case I would create an `std::string` from the result of `getenv` and then append to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sailing dangerous waters my friend

```
 char* path = getenv("LOCALAPPDATA");
 strcat(path, "\\myApp\\myLog.txt");
```

The variable `path` points to an internal memory block, you cannot use it this way.

The fact that your progra, does not blow up in `strcat(path, "\\myApp\\myLog.txt");` it's just another example of undefined behavior.

Try copying it's content to another variable before using it

```
std::string path = getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"); // beware getenv might return NULL
path += "\\myApp\\myLog.txt";
```

**Update:**
From my understanding, it's possible that the value of path ends up being `%LOCALAPPDATA%\\myApp\\myLog.txt\\myApp\\myLog.txt`, and the third time `%LOCALAPPDATA%\\myApp\\myLog.txt\\myApp\\myLog.txt\\myApp\\myLog.txt` and so on..

Comment: This corrected the behavior of my program. And yes I had noticed that same behavior where it created reoccurances of the directory. Phew! That was ugly.

Comment: Can I ask is it just a rule of thumb in c++ not to store that method getenv into a char pointer? Or just in general not use character pointers since they sometimes cause undefined behavior?